# Avoid validating attributes in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-attribute

How can I have an XSD which does not validate attribute of an element in my XML? Basically my xml has a tag which can have any attributes - For example:

```
<test attrib1="some val">Content here</test>
```

I wouldn't know beforehand if the attribute is going to be attrib1 or something else. How can I write an XSD that will avoid attrib1?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's very good design.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's our (rather unique) use case. The attributes and their values form a map when we deserialize the XML into an object.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it out myself ;-)

```
    <xs:complexType name="test">
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

That will do the trick. Now you can have your test element as below:

```
<xs:element name="test" type="test"/>
```